# AS400 Backup Inquiry?

Tags: backup, ibm-midrange

Can someone tell me the commands to view the status or logs of our backup jobs that are running on our AS400? Our sysadmin decided to walk out last week and I would like to check on these jobs to ensure that everything is running ok. Also, how can I see the properties of the backup job? I would like to ensure that all the proper tables etc are being backed up appropriately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using only simple standard system tools (no additional nor third party software) there are three main points you can start in greenscreen:

1. go backup
2. go save
3. dsplog and wrksplf

In the "backup" menu (1st option) you can check the status of backup (DSPBCKSTS) and redefine or run one (RUNBCKUP).

In the "save" menu you can make backup copy (commands begining with SAV*) of specified objects from the system. Restore is done using one of the RST* command.

Using dsplog (system log) you can check any error messages logged by application; and using wrksplf you can usually reach very detailed reports of almost any task.

If you are not very familiar with AS400 environments, the best (and probably the fastest) option will be to start with reading few chapters from IBM Information Center http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will definitely read up on the link provided as I have very little experience with the AS400. When I look under "go backup" and then "Display backup status" I am not seeing any history? We are also using JD Edwards software, could something have been setup within JDE? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Also check the job scheduler for any custom backup jobs:

```
WRKJOBSCDE
```